# F# - Why can’t I NOT use a pipeline operator in this code?

Tags: parameters, f#, pipeline

I’m probably missing something very fundamental here but I can’t figure out what it is.

I have some very basic code as below:

```
let myList = [1; 3; 5; 7; 5; 3; 9; 5; 2; 5; 3; 8]
let fiveOrLess = myList |> List.choose (fun number ->
    match number with
    | number when number <= 5 -> Some number
    | _ -> None)
```

… and that works just fine, as expected.

However, with the code below, where I have moved the “myList” from the pipe to just being a ‘normal’ parameter, I get two error messages from the compiler:

```
let myList = [1; 3; 5; 7; 5; 3; 9; 5; 2; 5; 3; 8]
let fiveOrLess = List.choose (fun number ->
    match number with
    | number when number <= 5 -> Some number
    | _ -> None) myList
```

Error FS3118 Incomplete value or function definition. If this is in an expression, the body of the expression must be indented to the same column as the 'let' keyword. *[This error on the second ‘let’.]*

Error FS0010 Unexpected identifier in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token. *[This error on the last “myList”.]*

Nether of these error messages makes much sense to me as all I have done is move a parameter ‘from one side to the other’.

The documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.choose%5b%27t%2c%27u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d shows code which has a very similar form to my second sample but that works okay.

Can anyone explain what silly, basic mistake I’ve made here?
Also, and possibly more importantly, can anyone explain what the error messages mean and why I’m getting them, both in general and in this context please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite a subtle formatting issue but it seems that putting an argument on the same line immediately after a multi-line lambda, which starts on a `let` line, is not valid. Your code had non-standard formatting in a few different ways but the F# compiler was being fairly permissive until that last part where it the parser completely lost track of things and wasn't able to provide a helpful error.

So it's not that your formatting was clearly "wrong", but once you're in the habit of writing F# code following normal formatting standards you would never have that problem. Here are some standard ways to format the function:

```
let fiveOrLess =
    List.choose
        (fun number ->
            match number with
            | number when number <= 5 -> Some number
            | _ -> None)
        myList
```

The indentation above makes it clear what the two arguments to `List.choose` are.

---

```
let fiveOrLess =
    myList
    |> List.choose (fun number ->
        match number with
        | number when number <= 5 -> Some number
        | _ -> None)
```

We use piping above so that the multi-line lambda is the very last parameter.

Comment: Ah, I see. Formatting that way makes it look much clearer. Thank you. The only reason why I formatted it the way I did was because that’s how it is formatted in the Microsoft documentation (see the link I gave above) and the book I am trying to learn from. In the link I gave, the Microsoft documentation has the argument on the same line immediately after the multi-line lambda. Is that documentation formatted incorrectly? If it is, that’s going to make learning this more difficult. P.S. Is there a way to make the compiler even less-permissive so I can see more potential problems earlier?

Comment: @GarryP Yes I see now that the documentation is not very good in that instance. The only thing you could do to change how the compiler responds to whitespace is to ignore specific warnings or treat them as errors. It wouldn't have helped in this case.

Comment: I’m going to look at reformatting other stuff that I have written to see how it looks. Hopefully I’ll just get used to things and it will become second nature to do it the better way. Thanks again for your time and advice.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're facing is indentation.

Try to indent further, like this:

```
let myList = [1; 3; 5; 7; 5; 3; 9; 5; 2; 5; 3; 8]
let fiveOrLess = List.choose (fun number ->
      match number with
      | number when number <= 5 -> Some number
      | _ -> None) myList
```

Also, note that in this case, you can use the `function` keyword

```
let myList = [1; 3; 5; 7; 5; 3; 9; 5; 2; 5; 3; 8]
let fiveOrLess = List.choose (function
        | number when number <= 5 -> Some number
        | _ -> None) myList
```

finally, unless this is a simplified repro, `filter` is your function in this case:

```
let myList = [1; 3; 5; 7; 5; 3; 9; 5; 2; 5; 3; 8]
let fiveOrLess = List.filter (fun n -> n <= 5) myList
```

Comment: Sorry, my original code had default 4-space indents which didn’t come over in the pasting/formatting into this site. I have altered the above code. 4-space indents work with the first version but not the second, 5-space indents work with the first version but not the second, **but** 6-space indents work with both. Also, 4-space indents on all the indented lines except the last where it has a 6-space indent works too. See next comment…

Comment: I’ve read https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-syntax/ and https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/470 but still can’t see what I did wrong. Renaming “fiveOrLess” to “fiveOrLe” fixes things but I don’t understand why. Is there a some kind of pattern which I’m not seeing? P.S. Thanks for the “function” tip, and I also need to try to understand how “choose” is different to “filter” (I just followed the Microsoft docs example).

Comment: @GarryP, the problem you're facing is due to "indentation relaxation". The official rule is to align with `fun` or `|>` (or any operator), but recently, several rules have been relaxed. An operator introduces a minor negative indent on the next line, which helps with alignment by text, not the operator. This rule is a little fuzzy, and in your example gets combined with another relaxation rule on `fun`, which usually introduces a new "indentation scope". I would argue your case here is a bug, albeit a small one, since the docs page shows it should work. You could add it to issue #470.

Comment: Thanks @Abel. It seems like I have much more to learn about fundamental things, such as formatting, than I expected to. I don’t think I would be comfortable adding to the conversation about issue #470 in Github just yet. The chat gets way to complicated for me as a beginner and I don’t want to look like I’m just dropping something onto the table and then running away. Maybe when I have a bit more experience and can handle some of the replies.